# How to find matching values in two maps in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find matching "level"s in two different maps (games - floating items) in flutter.  How can find those items and create a new map that key is "level" and value is matching floating Items? The sample code is below.

```
List <Game> games = [
    {
      "id": "Level 1",
      "level": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": "Level 2",
      "level": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": "Level 3",
      "level": 3,
    },
   ];


List <FloatingItem> floatingItems = [
    {
      "level": "1",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "level": "1",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "level": "3",
      "position": -5
    },
    {
      "level": "3",
       "position": 0
    },
    {
      "level": "2",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "level": "3",
      "position": -5
    },
   ];
```

Comment: There must be better way but For loop can work easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have these two list. I changed the type, since I don't know how the classes `Game` and `FloatingItem` looks like.

```
final List <Map<String, dynamic>> games = [
    {
      "id": "Level 1",
      "level": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": "Level 2",
      "level": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": "Level 3",
      "level": 3,
    },
];

final List <Map<String, dynamic>> floatingItems = [
    {
      "level": 1,
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "level": 1,
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "level": 3,
      "position": -5
    },
    {
      "level": 3,
       "position": 0
    },
    {
      "level": 2,
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "level": 3,
      "position": -5
    },
];
```

Here I create a new map by going through all `games` and set the key `level` and `floatingItems`.

```
final Map<String, dynamic>> newMap = games.map((game) => 
  {
    "level": game['level'],
    "floatingItems": floatingItems.where((item) => item['level'] == game['level']),
 });
```

The output

```
(
  {
    level: 1, 
    floatingItems: ({level: 1, position: 0}, {level: 1, position: 5})
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    floatingItems: ({level: 2, position: 5})
  }, 
  {
    level: 3,
    floatingItems: ({level: 3, position: -5}, {level: 3, position: 0},
                    {level: 3, position: -5})
  }
)
```